# Japanese onomatopoeia for "RRRip" in a horror context?

Tags: word-requests, onomatopoeia

I'm working on a horror comic and I'm looking for a reference for the onomatopoeia "RRRRip". The comic specifically deals with zombies, so "RRRRip" here would be referring to skin or flesh tearing. The closest thing I've seen online is めりっ but I'm not sure if there are other expressions that would fit better. I was thinking of using バリバリ, but I don't know if that would fit in this context. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a substantial amount of flesh (or a human body torn in two), メリメリ is better.

The following example (from [here](https://www.rondely.com/zakkaya/dic5/gt7-2.htm#m22)) may help to give an idea.

> めりめり 裂ける big/booming creaking (cracking) sound; loudly creak/crack/split
>
> 例文 Lightning struck and split the tree with a booming creaking sound.
>
> 稲光がして木がめりめりと裂けた。

メリ(ッ) would suggest the start of tearing (cracking).

If it is like peeling skin, メリメリ still works.

As for tearing a sheet of skin, ビリビリ or バリバリ may be better, just like tearing a sheet of paper. (Honestly, I cannot imagine the situation well)